# Read response headers from image error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, jquery-events

I have an `<img />` element in my page, and it's `src` attribute is regularly changed by Javascript.

When the `src` attribute changes, my code on the servers checks :

1. is the user logged in ?
2. does the image exist ?

then it sends a response accordingly, either the image or a response with error headers (Status `403 Forbidden` or `404 Not Found`).

Here's my problem : I handle the img error with the following code

```
$(function(){
    var $img = $('#test_image');
    $img.on('error',function(e){
        // here, I need to read the headers (at least status code)
        console.log(e);
    }).attr('src','http://example.com/loadimg.php?img=3');
});
```

I need to display a **distinct error message** if the user can't load the image because his session has expired or if the image he's trying to load doesn't exist.

**Where can I find the response headers and/or status code in the `eventObject` from the handler ?**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AuSN/)

Comment: You cannot get the headers of a request made by the browser internally due to changing the `src` attribute of an element. Instead you would need to make an AJAX call yourself, returning the imagine in BLOB format (as a string), and if there is an error you could then get the error codes generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the overhead isn't too much for you, you could send a Head request to see what the return is in case of error

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('HEAD', url, true); // True is for async
http.send();
if (http.status == 404) {
    //
} else if (http.status == 403) {
    //
} else {
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll use something like this.


$.ajax({
        type: "HEAD",
        async: true,
        url: imgSrc,
        complete: function(jqXHR,text){
            statusCode = jqXHR.status;
     
        }
});